# Error en Moodle (Docker+nginx reverse proxy) Reverse proxy enabled, server can not be accessed directly, sorry

Tags: docker, nginx, moodle

Mediante contenedores docker estoy intentando levantar un Moodle. Entre otros estos son los contenedores que estoy utilizando:

- jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy
- jauer/moodle https://hub.docker.com/r/jauer/moodle/

He configurado el fichero `config.php` de moodle descomentado algunas lineas y dejandolo de esta manera:

`$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://moodle.mydomain.com';`

`$CFG->reverseproxy = true;`

`$CFG->sslproxy = true;`

Pero al acceder a la web sigo recibiendo el mismo error.

> Reverse proxy enabled, server can not be accessed directly, sorry.

Comment: Parece que estás accediendo desde el navegador al contenedor con PHP, no? Pero entiendo que deberías acceder al de nginx, que debería estar configurado como proxy para el de PHP (ambos contenedores deberían ejecutarse en una misma red docker para simplificar la configuración)

Comment: En principios ambos contenedores los ejecuto en la misma red Docker utilizando el valor de `networks`

Comment: No he tocado mucho nginx pero si no recuerdo mal hay que crear un fichero de configuración para cada servicio al que queramos acceder ¿no?. En ese fichero indicamos que puerto se está escuchando, desde donde se hace la peticion (moodle.midominio.com) y a donde hay que redirigirlo: tu_IP:8080

Eso es lo que recuerdo de mi paso por nginx. Espero te ayude un poco.